# Need advice on how to use FindFit

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, warning-messages

I have written the following code in Mathematica

```
f1[u_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ] := 
  Y /. 
    FindRoot[
      1 - (1 - u) Y - u (1 + 3.14^2/(r Y^((2 0.63 - 1)/0.62))^2)^(1/2) Y^(0.63/.52), 
      {Y, 0.000001, 1}];

rf1[u_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ] := 
  3.14^2/(Sqrt[r f1[u, r]^((2 0.63 - 1)/0.62)]^4) 
    (1 + 3.14^2/Sqrt[r f1[u, r]^((2 0.63 - 1)/0.62)]^2)^(-1) 
    (0.63/0.52 + ((1 - u) f1[u, r])/(1 - (1 - u) f1[u, r]))^(-1);

rf2[u_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ] := -((2 0.63 - 1)/0.52) r f1[u, r]^((2 0.63 - 1)/0.62);

f2[u_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ] := 
  1/0.52*(rf1[u, r] r f1[u, r]^((2 0.63 - 1)/0.62))/(1 + rf1[u, r] rf2[u, r])

w0 = -1;
w1 = 1.5 ;
w2 = -1.4;
w3 = -0.8;
w4 = 0.07;
b = 2.691047;

w[theta_?NumberQ, l0_?NumberQ, m0_?NumberQ] := 
  m0 l0 (w0 + w1 theta^2 + w2 theta^4 + w3 theta^6 + w4 theta^8);
wp[theta_, l0_, m0_] := D[w[theta, l0, m0], theta];

l[theta_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ] := l0 theta (1 - theta^2);
lp[theta_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ] := -2 l0 theta^2 + l0 (1 - theta^2);
k[theta_?NumericQ] := (1 - b theta^2);
kp[theta_?NumericQ] := -3.382094 theta;

data = 
  {{127481.8183296798`, 0.001`}, {1990.5248645895465`, 0.011`}, 
   {650.2050275373107`, 0.021`}, {331.742608489351`, 0.031`}, 
   {204.75942189403582`, 0.041`}, {140.54519314852138`, 0.051000000000000004`}, 
   {103.24315592880238`, 0.061`}, {79.5018435395663`, 0.07100000000000001`}, 
   {63.37868794896939`, 0.081`}, {51.88495362079122`, 0.091`}}

m[theta_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ] := 
  ((2 - 0.11 f2[u, r]) w[theta, l0, m0] kp[theta] - 
   wp[theta, l0, m0] k[theta])/(lp[theta, l0] k[theta] - 
   (3/2 + 0.325 4.8 - 3/2) f2[u, r] l[theta, l0] kp[theta]);
cdd1[theta_, r_, u_, l0_, m0_] := Block[{x}, ND[m[theta, x, u, l0, m0], x, r]]
```

At this point when I use

```
FindFit[data, cdd1[1, r, u , l0, m0] , {u, l0, m0}, r]
```

But I get various errors for example "1 is not a valid variable.", it seems as I am not experienced in Mathematica, even with `NonlinearModelFit` I get error, I don't know where I made mistake.
Could you please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The primary error here is from your definition of `wp` (and also through `w`). You can't take the derivative with respect to $\theta$ having put $\theta=1$ into the equation already. Try replacing them with:

```
w[theta_, l0_?NumberQ, m0_?NumberQ] := 
  m0 l0 (w0 + w1 theta^2 + w2 theta^4 + w3 theta^6 + w4 theta^8);

wp[theta_, l0_, m0_] := D[w[th, l0, m0], th] /. th -> theta;
```

(There are other ways to do this for `wp`).

This lets me evaluate cdd1 for numerical values successfully.

Answer (score 0):

these defs should not be be `SetDelayed` or `NumericQ` :

```
w[theta_, l0_, m0_] = 
  m0 l0 (w0 + w1 theta^2 + w2 theta^4 + w3 theta^6 + w4 theta^8);
wp[theta_, l0_, m0_] = D[w[theta, l0, m0], theta];
```

then you can not (I think) use `FindFit` where the fit parameters need to be numeric.  Try this:

```
FindMinimum[
 Total[(cdd1[1, #[[1]], u, l0, m0] - #[[2]])^2 & /@ data ] , {{u, 
   1}, {l0, 1}, {m0, 1}}]
```

> {0.00512945, {u -> 0.819404, l0 -> 13062.9, m0 -> 164.599}}

Edit: yes you can use `FindFit`. It takes a lot longer to give a similarly poor result.

```
FindFit[data, cdd1[1, x, u, l0, m0], {{u, 1}, {l0, 1}, {m0, 1}}, x]
```

the fit quality here is not good, but it may be your function just doesn't fit, or maybe you need to  find better start parameters.

Edit-the whole code

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"] (*for ND*)
f1[u_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ] := 
  Y /. FindRoot[
    1 - (1 - u) Y - 
     u (1 + 3.14^2/(r Y^((2 0.63 - 1)/0.62))^2)^(1/
         2) Y^(0.63/.52), {Y, 0.000001, 1}];
rf1[u_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ] := 
  3.14^2/(Sqrt[r f1[u, r]^((2 0.63 - 1)/0.62)]^4) (1 + 
      3.14^2/Sqrt[r f1[u, r]^((2 0.63 - 1)/0.62)]^2)^(-1) (0.63/
       0.52 + ((1 - u) f1[u, r])/(1 - (1 - u) f1[u, r]))^(-1);
rf2[u_?NumberQ, 
   r_?NumberQ] := -((2 0.63 - 1)/0.52) r f1[u, r]^((2 0.63 - 1)/0.62);
f2[u_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ] := 
 1/0.52*(rf1[u, r] r f1[u, r]^((2 0.63 - 1)/0.62))/(1 + 
     rf1[u, r] rf2[u, r])
w0 = -1;
w1 = 1.5;
w2 = -1.4;
w3 = -0.8;
w4 = 0.07;
b = 2.691047;
w[theta_, l0_, m0_] = 
  m0 l0 (w0 + w1 theta^2 + w2 theta^4 + w3 theta^6 + w4 theta^8);
wp[theta_, l0_, m0_] = D[w[theta, l0, m0], theta];
l[theta_, l0_] = l0 theta (1 - theta^2);
lp[theta_, l0_] = -2 l0 theta^2 + l0 (1 - theta^2);
k[theta_] = (1 - b theta^2);
kp[theta_] = -3.382094 theta;
data = {{127481.8183296798`, 0.001`}, {1990.5248645895465`, 
   0.011`}, {650.2050275373107`, 0.021`}, {331.742608489351`, 
   0.031`}, {204.75942189403582`, 0.041`}, {140.54519314852138`, 
   0.051000000000000004`}, {103.24315592880238`, 
   0.061`}, {79.5018435395663`, 
   0.07100000000000001`}, {63.37868794896939`, 
   0.081`}, {51.88495362079122`, 0.091`}}
m[theta_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ, 
   m0_?NumericQ] := ((2 - 0.11 f2[u, r]) w[theta, l0, m0] kp[theta] - 
     wp[theta, l0, m0] k[theta])/(lp[theta, l0] k[
       theta] - (3/2 + 0.325 4.8 - 3/2) f2[u, r] l[theta, l0] kp[
       theta]);
cdd1[theta_, r_, u_, l0_, m0_] := 
 Block[{x}, ND[m[theta, x, u, l0, m0], x, r]]
fit = FindMinimum[
  Total[(cdd1[1, #[[1]], u, l0, m0] - #[[2]])^2 & /@ data], {{u, 
    1}, {l0, 1}, {m0, 1}}]
```

Comment: @ george2079 Thanks, but  I got this problem FindMinimum::nrlnum: The function value {1.41421 (-12.+Global`ND[m[1.,x,1.,1.,1.],x,1.]),1.41421 (-10.+Global`ND[m[1.,x,1.,1.,1.],x,1.9]),1.41421 (-8.2+Global`ND[m[1.,x,1.,1.,1.],x,2.6]),1.41421 (-6.9+Global`ND[m[1.,x,1.,1.,1.],x,3.4]),1.41421 (-5.9+Global`ND[m[1.,x,1.,1.,1.],x,5.])} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {5} at {u,l0,m0} = {1.,1.,1.}. >> could youplease help me?

Comment: i pasted the whole code I ran into the answer.  maybe you need to  restart your kernel.